# Script gives "unexpected error near elif [ $1 = "-h" ] while syntax is correct

Tags: bash, parameters

While trying to run this command in the terminal:

```
gerard@yoda ~$ Sources/Scripts/ultimate.sh -u -typecount -std /usr/bin py
Sources/Scripts/ultimate.sh: line 28: syntax error near unexpected token `elif'
Sources/Scripts/ultimate.sh: line 28: `elif [ $1 = "-h" ];'
```

this is the source of the script:

```
#!/bin/bash

## $1 = Mode(u/h) ; $2 = Command(?) ; $3+ = Params

if [ $1 = "-u" ];
    if [ $2 = "-typecount" ];
    then
        if [ $3 = "-std" ];
        then
            find $4 -maxdepth 1 -iname *.$5 | wc -l
        elif [ $3 = "-ext" ];
        then
            find $5 -maxdepth $4 -iname *.$6 | wc -l
        else
            echo 'use option -std for single-dir'
            echo 'or option -def for recusive with custom depth'
            echo 'filetype should be defined  type  instead of .type'
        fi
    elif [ $2 = "-prep" ];
    then
        sed -i 's/^/$3/' $4
    elif [ $2 = "-app" ];
    then
        sed -i 's/$/$3/' $4
    else
        echo 'No command specified/Command not found'
    fi
elif [ $1 = "-h" ];
then
    if [ $2 = "-typecount" ];
    then
        echo 'for -std: [location] [type]'
        echo 'for -ext: [depth] [location] [type]'
    elif [ $2 = "-prep" ];
    then
        echo '[text] [file]'
    elif [$2 = "-app" ];
    then
        echo '[text] [file]'
    else
        echo 'No command specified/Command not found'
else
    echo 'No mode specified/Wrong mode'
fi
```

The syntax appears correct to me, and a simpler version of the script, with same elif construction works fine. What did I do wrong? (the script needs to quit after the desired function is parsed)

Comment: Since you are using bash, you should probably replace all `[`/`]` with `[[`/`]]` and quote all variables : `"$1"` instead of `$1`.

Comment: Stylistic note: the semicolon is unnecessary at the end of a line. The reason to use a semicolon in an `if` statement is to put the `then` on the same line as the `if`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the top you don't have a `then` keyword after the first `if`.

```
if [ $1 = "-u" ];
**then**
    if [ $2 = "-typecount" ];
```

You're also missing an `fi` near the bottom:

```
    else
        echo 'No command specified/Command not found'
    **fi**
else
```

Comment: Thanks! Can't believe I didn't see that the whole time.. It works like a charm!